# How to get gps location with seconds precision?

Tags: android, gps, precision

I'm trying to get the gps current position to my Android app, using locationManager.requestLocationUpdates I'm getting my position with degrees precision, but I need to get the seconds.
Is it possible to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using coarse location or fine?

Comment: I'm using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GPS, you should be accurate to within about 10 meters, which is less than 1 second of longitude (unless you're close to a pole).  If you're using network then you just can't get that amount, you can only get to a few hundred meters.

If you need the actual number of seconds, you can convert the fractional degrees to minutes and seconds.  Each degree is 60 minutes, so fractional_degrees*60 is the number of minutes, and fractional_minutes*60 is the number of seconds.